# How to add mouse pointer or cursor to existing screenshot?

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, annotations

Many years ago, I had a program that could take a screenshot, and from within the program, I could add mouse pointers (as many as I wanted) to me screenshot *after it was taken*.  I have been Googling things like 'add cursor to existing screenshot' and 'add mouse pointer to image' to try to find out what I used, but I'm not seeing anything close to what I want in the first two pages of results.

I'm aware that there are many screen capture utilities that can include the mouse pointer or cursor in the screen shot.  I also know that almost any image editing program can add a pointer to an image or screenshot.  But what I am looking for is an *easy, simple, and quick* way to add a mouse pointer or cursor to an already existing image or screenshot.

Comment: Some quick feedback on why this was closed despite being a self-answered question: Original wording was an off-topic software request.  These are undesirable because they attract lists of products instead of solutions.  Your answer is a product list.  The question would continue to attract similar answers--everybody's favorite product.  The edit removed the product request, but what's left is too broad.  You can position and paste a cursor image into a screenshot with any image editor.  The question doesn't describe what you tried and what problem you were unable to solve. (cont'd)

Comment: You might be able to salvage the thread by being more specific in the question about the actual problem.  Then expand the answer to address how to solve that problem using the tool, or at least what makes those tools an especially good solution to the problem as opposed to random Google hits.

Comment: Is the question acceptable now?  I just discovered softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but I'm really not looking for a software recommendation.  It's an honest question that I thought would be appropriate for superuser.  Let me know if you'd rather I migrate it to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In my answer, the second solution is a web app, not software.

Comment: You could probably force-fit the question here with enough work, but really, this is the wrong site for it.  Your goal is a product recommendation and the question is a perfect fit for that site.

Comment: K.  Will do.  You can nuke this question then, or is that something I should do?

Comment: FWIW, I still think this is a useful question here on Superuser.  Superuser has nice tags for screen-capture and screenshot.

Comment: Moved question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38654/28872

Comment: Already some upvotes on this question.  Some have found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the program you used was [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html), a circa 2002 program that still runs on Windows 10, and has the ability to add various cursors and pointers to images.

Then there's [Cursor that Screenshot](http://edbentley.github.io/cursor-that-screenshot/), a GitHub repository and website that allows you to upload an image and add a cursor to it using just your web browser.